# Консоль хрома выдает ошибку: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token" JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```js
var typed1 = new Typed("#typed1") {
  strings: ["Hello.", "Greettings.", "Hey.", "Welcome.", "Howdy.", "Shalom.", "Hi."],
  // typing speed
  typeSpeed: 40,
  // time before typing starts
  startDelay: 1000,
  //time before erasing starts
  backDelay: 1000,
  // backspacing speed
  backSpeed: 60,
  // loop
  loop: true,
  // false = infinite
  loopCount: 5,
  // show cursor
  showCursor: true,
  // character for cursor
  cursorChar: "|",
  // attribute to type (null == text)
};
```

Консоль гласит, что ошибка на первой строке.

Comment: Правильно гласит. Где Вы взяли этот синтаксис?

Comment: На оффициальном сайте разработчика скрипта Typed.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опции идут вторым параметром:

```
var typed1 = new Typed("#typed1", {
  strings: ["Hello.", "Greettings.", "Hey.", "Welcome.", "Howdy.", "Shalom.", "Hi."],
  // typing speed
  typeSpeed: 40,
  // time before typing starts
  startDelay: 1000,
  //time before erasing starts
  backDelay: 1000,
  // backspacing speed
  backSpeed: 60,
  // loop
  loop: true,
  // false = infinite
  loopCount: 5,
  // show cursor
  showCursor: true,
  // character for cursor
  cursorChar: "|",
  // attribute to type (null == text)
});
```

Comment: Теперь ошибки появились в Typed.js (библиотека для анимации)

Comment: "не отображает внешний JavaScript" - Вы с кем сейчас разговариваете?

Comment: Какие ошибки? Что он должен отображать?

Comment: Вот ошибки, которые появляются при выполнении вашего кода: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
    at Initializer.load (typed.js:647)
    at new Typed (typed.js:116)
    at typed-user.js:1"

Comment: @DimaSoltusyuk добавьте в страницу DOM-элемент с `id="typed1"`

Comment: @Igor typed-user.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: @DimaSoltusyuk попробуйте создать нормальный пример, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода" в редакторе вопроса

Answer (score 0):

```js
var typed1 = new Typed("#typed1");
console.log(typed1);

function Typed(selector) {
  this.strings = ["Hello.", "Greettings.", "Hey.", "Welcome.", "Howdy.", "Shalom.", "Hi."];
  // typing speed
  this.typeSpeed = 40;
  // time before typing starts
  this.startDelay = 1000;
  //time before erasing starts
  this.backDelay = 1000;
  // backspacing speed
  this.backSpeed = 60;
  // loop
  this.loop = true;
  // false = infinite
  this.loopCount = 5;
  // show cursor
  this.showCursor = true;
  // character for cursor
  this.cursorChar = "|";
  // attribute to type (null == text)
};
```

Comment: Ошибок нет, ответ верен. Но внешний JavaScript просто не выполняется.